# IBAction not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uibarbuttonitem called nextButton in storyboard that goes to another ViewController with a segue. But when I try to add this method on another file:

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Hello")
}
```

the output does not show up on the console. The only way I have gotten the button to display this message is when I take out the segue in the storyboard. When I do that, I add the following method so that on clicking the button the segue is done programmatically:

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Hello");

    GameDetailsTableViewController *gameDetails = [[GameDetailsTableViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: gameDetails animated:YES];
}
```

But when I do this, the console shows an error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

I need help to figure out how to make sure that the button displays the message and goes to the next view controller on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A button can be assigned to either an `IBAction` method or a segue.

If you use a segue, implement `-prepareForSegue:sender:` in your controller to run any additional code when the segue is executed.  E.g.:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqual:@"gameDetailSegue"])
    {
        GameDetailsTableViewController* gameDetails = (id)[segue destinationViewController];
        gameDetails.cheatMode = self.prefs.cheatModeEnabled;
    }
}
```

If you use an action method then you have to present the view controller manually.  You also have to instantiate the view controller from your storyboard:

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    GameDetailsTableViewController* gameDetails = 
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameDetailController"]
    gameDetails.cheatMode = self.prefs.cheatModeEnabled;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gameDetails animated:YES];
}
```

In either case, you must assign identifiers to your segues and view controllers in your storyboard.

Comment: As @darren said you have to approach in either way as defined in the provided answer and if you wish you can also try it doing via storyboard by connecting the Uibutton to the next view and provided the necessary options like push/modal etc.., hope this helps.